# Trouble Understanding Syntax for Props Access in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

In the example given for `<Formik />` [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik) we can gain access to the Formik context props in children with this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

const BasicExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: 'jared' }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
      }}
    >
      {props => (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
            value={props.values.name}
            name="name"
          />
          {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
```

I'm having an issue understanding what's happening here:

```
>
  {props => (
```

Where is this 'props' coming from and what sort of syntax is this. I have a feeling the syntactic sugar of the `<Formik />` is making this harder to wrap my head around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props you get there are known as render props, please refer to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) link for official documentation.

Render Props are a way of passing props down to the children

Using this style pattern, we render children as a function & we can pass parameters to that

In the same way, `<Formik/>` passding down some `renderProps` down the children

you can refer to [this](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/src/Formik.tsx#L931) `<Formik/>` component code, if you want to see how the props are being passed & how the children are being rendered

Please refer to [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-render-props) article with detailed explanation of render props

Please refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-thunder-nk9b2) code sandbox for live example

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in JSX anything inside two tags is the children.

E.g

```
<div>
  I’m the child
</div>
```

Well what if you make the children a function?

```
<div>
   {() => { console.log('The children has been executed')}
</div>
```

Well, if the wrapping component expects it’s children to be a function (the same as an onClick prop is a function) it can call it and pass data when it does.

This is a way of using data from a child component as input to determine what to render.

Here formik is one such component - and it will pass the form props to the children function. This is also known as render props.